# os.rmdir in premake cannot be used in normal lua

Tags: lua, premake

From premake cookbook, I get the following code:

```
solution "MySolution"
  configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

  configuration { "Debug" }
    targetdir "bin/debug"

  configuration { "Release" }
    targetdir "bin/release"

  if _ACTION == "clean" then
    os.rmdir("bin")
  end
```

and I tried os.rmdir("bin") in my normal lua app, put it in my hello1.lua, run it with this command:

```
lua hello1.lua
```

But get error:

```
lua: hello1.lua:11: attempt to call field 'rmdir' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    hello1.lua:11: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

It seems the os.rmdir is not standard lua function, just from premake4, am I right? 
Where can I find the document for os.rmdir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [premake scripting reference](http://industriousone.com/scripting-reference).

This is [os.rmdir](http://industriousone.com/osrmdir) specific page.